# How to output two results in a function R

Tags: r, class, object

```
library(Matching)        
F01 <- function(...){
      m <- outer(1:50, 1:50, Vectorize(function(i,j)
      {ks.boot(as.numeric(rep(seq(0,14,1),as.vector(data[i,]))),
               as.numeric(rep(seq(0,14,1),
                              as.vector(data[j,]))),nboots=10000)$ks.boot.pvalue}))
      rownames(m) <- data[, 1]
      d=as.dist(as.matrix(1-m))
      hcr <- hclust(d,method = "complete")
      dend <- as.dendrogram(hcr)
    }
dendy <- lapply(1:25, F01)
```

This will output just `dend`. How do I get it to output both hcr and dend?

Comment: function `F01` errors in my session on creation, can you check it please?

Comment: should be fixed

Comment: Now the error is in `data` it's an `object of type 'closure'` Also, you should start the script with a call to `library()`, function `ks.boot` is not a base function.

Comment: I'm not sure why you are getting the `data` error. I've updated the script for with the library and I also used `as.hclust(dend01[[1]])` to transform `dend01[[1]]` back into hcr class but the names are still weird. Nevertheless I think I will have to play around with it to get the labels correct.

Comment: I will change the question slightly

Comment: `data` is a base R function, for your example you have most probably defined it as a data.frame, so your example isn't reproducible

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have `list(hcr= hcr, dend=dend)` as your last line in your function.

Then you can use `purrr::transpose` on it to get a list with a `hcr` list element and a `dend` list element.

Finally if you really want 2 objects in your workspace, which i wouldn't recommend, you can use `list2env` on the result.

Comment: thanks for your answer. It seems to have resolved the issue I was having.